# VS2015 Domain project(class library) after loading not fully accessible

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have 2 VS solutions.

The first solution has a WebUI project in .Net 4.5.2 and a Domain project also in .Net 4.5.2. The WebUI depends on the Domain and holds a reference to it. The Domain builds first. Everything works.

The second solution has a WebUI project in .Net 4.6. I "added" the Domain project from the first solution here (by clicking right mouse on my solution name --> Add --> Existing project).

I added a reference here also and the Domain builds before the WebUI just as in my first solution. Things work correct, for example, I can create a viewmodel in my WebUI and reference to a domain class. I can also acces the domain classes after using an import statement in my controllers. See second pic where I use the person class and contact class. This all works fine. I have some issues however.

In the WebUi's when I want to generate a mvc5 controller using entity framework in my first solution I see in the model class dropdown list my domain entities.
[image]

However, I don't see these entities(Domain.DbEntities) in my second solution in the dropdown, which I find very strange since I can acces the domain entities from whitin code-files which you can see in de background(i.e. 'person' and 'contact' in my EditPerson(int id) action method
[image]

Anybody an idea why?

Comment: This is Visual Studio Intellisense. It is intelligent enough to know which models it can create controllers for with EF . It is not a bug. It simply means Domain.DbEntities cannot be used here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the different framework version is the problem.
Have you build the project already?

See also: [Add Controller Model Classes not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758493/add-controller-model-classes-not-shown)